# Viewing Doxygen results

Tags: c++, linux, doxygen

I have tried running doxygen from my Linux terminal using the commands:
`doxygen -g`, followed by
`doxygen Doxyfile`

I then get the corresponding *html* sub-directory produced in the directory that my original code is stored in. However, when I open the *index.html* file in Google Chrome, I do not get any results being displayed - I just get a blank page saying My Project Documentation as shown below. Why is this the case?

[image: Doxygen HTML results]

Comment: Doxygen version 1.8.13 is a bit older (December 2016), the current version is 1.9.1. What are the extensions of the files used and wher do thet reside (current directory it looks like from the description). Any error messages on your console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you actually edited the Doxyfile that gets produced? There are a few lines in there that you want to look at:

```
PROJECT_NAME           = "My Project Name"
INPUT                  += src
```

Also, when I ran it, I don't specify the Doxyfile, but that's just because Doxyfile is used by default.